# Publisher Confirms - Rabbit mq

Tags: spring-boot

I want to implement **publisher confirms** functionality into my code, gone through the http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/ but was unable to understand

I am using QueueBuilder as follows

```
@Bean
public Queue salesQueue() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable(salesQueue)
        .withArgument("x-max-length", 1)
        .withArgument("x-overflow", "reject-publish")
        .build();
}
```

RabbitTemplate creation

```
@Bean
public AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) 
{
final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback((correlationData, ack, cause) -> {
    if (ack) {
       System.out.println("Message with correlation ID {} confirmed by 
       broker."+ correlationData.getId());
    } else {
            System.out.println("Broker is unable to handle message with 
            correlation ID {} : {}"+correlationData.getId()+","+
                    cause);
           }

    });
return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

sending message to queue

```
@Service
public class RabbitMQSender {
private static long sentMessageCount =0L;
@Autowired
private AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Value("${rabbitmq.queue}")
String queueName;   
public void send() {
    long x=++sentMessageCount;
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName," 
    {'empId':'"+x+"','empName':'YYYYYY'}");
}
```

Presently I have set the queue length as 1, whenever I send messages greater than 1, I am expecting it to inform publisher about rejection of message via a basic.nack message which is not happening...

I request you to help me with this

Thank you

Comment: Please include the relevant error messages within your question, Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)